# How to conveniently read chunks of a file to QByteArray?

Tags: c++, qt, qfile, qbytearray

I want to send chunks of a file over network. I want to send them as individual `QByteArray`s, say by 200 bytes. I thought I can use `QFile`, but I don't understand what is wrong with it. I try to open the file at given path and then start sending it asynchronously:

```
QByteArray readFileChunk(QFileInfo filePath, quint64 offset, quint64 minLength)
{
    if(filePath.isFile() && filePath.isReadable()) {

        // Prepare the file instance and reset the byte count to 0             
        QFile currentFile(filePath.absoluteFilePath());
    }
}
```

I do not know how to read range from X to Y from a file as `QByteArray`. I found no concise example on the internet so I'm posting this question.

Comment: I don't see how the question title is related to the compilation error.

Comment: I removed the error which was distracting from the question. Still I can't see why this question deserves downvotes, it was pretty clear even before the edit.

Comment: You can use the [`QFile::read`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#read-1) overload to read a max number of bytes from a source.  Is that what you're after?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transferring large files over TCP in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065463/transferring-large-files-over-tcp-in-qt)

Comment: Please show the contents of `sendDatagram` and explain the details of the protocol you're using. Most likely `sendDatagram` is written in a blocking fashion. You should invert the control flow so that datagrams are sent as fast as the network is able to accept them and no faster, and the file reading should be relegated to an I/O thread as Qt doesn't provide an asynchronous `QFile`.

Comment: I am confused. The question is how to read chunk of a file, not how to send that chunk over network. I thought the question title is pretty clear!